# Addition [tag:no-boost]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, meta-tags

For those who can't use boost, there should be a tag that exists to simplify specifying that boost is not an option for an answer. I understand that SO answers are meant to be as a resource for many, but it is fairly obnoxious to have to specify that boost is not an option. I also feels it clutters the question.

Comment: Is this for the Turbo button?

Comment: @random Turbo button?

Comment: It's a joke. "Turbo" and "boost" go together.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If they don't pay attention to it in the body of your question, what makes you think they'll pay attention to it as a tag? If people post answers that use Boost and you've specifically requested a solution that does not use Boost, **downvote it** as it's not helpful. That's what downvotes are for. I do this on questions which specifically ask for a CSS solution but someone provides JavaScript instead.

This isn't want tags are for.

Comment: Most of the time I see "Edit: Boost is not an option" in parts of the question. Sometimes even I forget to mention it when I'm composing the question.

Comment: But, you'd remember to add it as a tag instead?

Comment: @animuson Probably. I hardly ever use the 5 tag limit anyway and I'm always trying to find tags that are relevant.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Don't do this.  `no-` anything is never acceptable.  Such tags are going to be edited out pretty much right away by anyone paying attention to the new tag list.  It's an abuse of the tag system and may even be considered a meta tag.